# Access JavaScript object property using Java

Tags: java, javascript, object, properties

Here is the JS code:

```
var build_info = new Object;

build_info.BUILD_DISPLAY_VERSION       = "Build 201302232300";
```

Here is the Java code:

```
    ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine jsEngine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    jsEngine.eval(buildInfoJS);
    buildInfoObj =  jsEngine.get("build_info.BUILD_DISPLAY_VERSION");
```

However, buildInfoObj comes back as null.

If I use `buildInfoObj =  jsEngine.get("build_info");` I get an object of class sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.NativeObject, which I understand is a restricted class.

Is there an easy way of accessing the build_info.BUILD_DISPLAY_VERSION property that I'm overlooking?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to get the javascript object `build_info` instead of `build_info.BUILD_DISPLAY_VERSION` and use the mozilla internal `NativeObject`

The following code should print out:

```
BUILD_DISPLAY_VERSION
Build 201302232300
```

Here's the source (I made the syntax as Java as possible, but I'm testing this under Groovy)

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.SimpleBindings;
import sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.NativeObject;

String buildInfoJS = "var build_info = new Object;build_info.BUILD_DISPLAY_VERSION       = 'Build 201302232300'";
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine jsEngine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
jsEngine.eval(buildInfoJS);
Object nativeObject = jsEngine.get("build_info");

if (nativeObject instanceof NativeObject) {
    NativeObject nObj = (NativeObject)nativeObject;
    for (String key: nObj.getAllIds()) {
        System.out.println(key);
        System.out.println(nObj.get(key, nObj));
    }
}
```

Reference:
This seems to be related to the following question, although for Groovy: [How to execute Javascript code from groovy and get the results as a map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348587/how-to-execute-javascript-code-from-groovy-and-get-the-results-as-a-map)

Comment: Is it safe to use `sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.NativeObject`? Since it is a class which placed in `internal`package.

Answer (score -1):

You're going to need to look at either the [context](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html#getContext%28%29) or [bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html#getBindings%28int%29) property of your jsEngine instance.

I believe calling 'get' on the jsEngine is only going to result in properties set on the engine NOT values set DURING execution of a script.

Comment: calling `get` will return objects created during script execution